# Bootstrap 4 modal menu links not clickables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, overlay

I have a problem with BS4 modal. I've readed an article where was explained how to create a simple overlay menù using Bootstrap modal. I've decided to give it a try but the links in the modal that will act as a menù aren't clickable. Here is the code. I hope someone can help me to fix this.

NB: I've already tried to link the `<a href="">` tags to the various pages but the problem persist.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#" alt="logo"></a>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nav-modal" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" id="menu-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>    
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="modal fade" id="nav-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-nav-content">
            <div class="row modal-nav-body">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" id="home">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" id="about">Chi siamo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" id="services">Servizi</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" id="contacts">Contatti</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check this link [https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSSBPGA688JT]

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the problem. now i need only to style the `.modal-content`. It seems that the problem was about the custom class `.modal-nav-content`. I don't know why but this will break the `<a href="">` linking.

Comment: Yes @user9741470 you need to apply style only to custom class i.e. `modal-nav-content`

Answer (score 0):

try javascript inline to force the event

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href='http://link-here' onclick='window.open("http://link-here.com");return 
  false;'>your menu</a>
</li>
```